# Show vote count on filtered questions list

Tags: feature-request, tag-filters, question-lists

Currently, the filtered questions list shows the amount of answers, but not the amount of votes:

[image]

The on-site question list does:

[image]

(From [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com))

*Why not show the votes in the filtered questions too?*

Comment: "By design." :p